# ImportError: cannot import name 'solvent' from partially initialized module 'api.views' in django rest api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-celery

I am using Django rest framework to do prediction on two strings and using celery to run inference. But I am getting error when trying to take `solute` and `solvent` from the result function into `tasks.py` file but I am getting error `ImportError: cannot import name 'solvent' from partially initialized module 'api.views'`

My `views.py` file

```py
from .tasks import predictions

@api_view(['GET'])
def result(request):
    response = {}
    solute = request.GET.get('solute')
    solvent = request.GET.get('solvent')
    results = predictions.delay()
    response["interaction_map"] = (results[1].detach().numpy()).tolist()
    response["predictions"] = results[0].item()
    return Response({'result': response}, status=200)
```

My `tasks.py` file

```py
@shared_task(bind=True)
def predictions(self):

    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(solute)
    mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)
    solute = Chem.MolToSmiles(mol)
    solute_graph = get_graph_from_smile(solute)

    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(solvent)
    mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)
    solvent = Chem.MolToSmiles(mol)
    solvent_graph = get_graph_from_smile(solvent)


    delta_g, interaction_map =  model([solute_graph.to(device), solvent_graph.to(device)])
    return delta_g, torch.trunc(interaction_map)
```

Comment: Can you please show your import statements?

Comment: @Josewails                                                                                                                     

`from rest_framework.decorators import api_view`
`from .serializer import Prediction`
`from rest_framework import serializers`
`from .tasks import predictions`